# Fake REST server in node.js

Tags: node.js, rest

Many times I need a REST server with fake data, to start coding before other service is finished.

I need an easy and fast way to create a fake REST server, based  on a config file. The fake server must allow to configure several routes, specifying the HTTP method, and the returned payload and HTTP code (that could be different depending on parameters in query string or path).

It will be a plus that the payload could be configured to be JSON or plain text (depending on the service). A node.js module will be the best option, but other options will be ok if they do the job.

Comment: Do you want fake-server to have your apis or just some result will do?

Comment: The responses must complain the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the JSON Server:

- https://github.com/typicode/json-server
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

From the readme:

> "Get a full fake REST API with zero coding in less than 30 seconds (seriously)"

It powers the JSON Placeholder:

- https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

that lets you create fake REST APIs without even starting your own server.